# An Example for submitting a task asynchronously (spooling) in a function

Tags: python, asynchronous

I am a newcomer in this field and I am trying to come up with a function that will accomplish the following:

1. Read data from an Oracle DB using large chunks (50000 rows).
2. For each chunk read, I want to spawn a thread or a process or something equivalent that will spool the chunk of data asynchronously(using CVS_Writer) to a file.
3. I don't want to block the data reading task to wait for the spooling operation to finish basically.

I have looked at something like below. Updated code with imports and removed the usage of Queue. Instead passing data chunk directly to the print function.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------

from __future__ import print_function

import cx_Oracle
import csv
import time
import datetime
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import Queue
def PrintRows(rows):
    rows=q.get()
    if not rows:
        return -1;
    csvf = open('sales_history.csv', 'a')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvf,delimiter='|')
    print ("In PrintRows function : ")
    csv_writer.writerows(rows)
    csvf.close()
    return 0

def TheMainQuery():
 conn = pool.acquire()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.arraysize = 80000
    cursor.execute("""
         select *
            from
                sales_history
                """)
    rows = cursor.fetchmany()
    while rows:
        if not rows:
           break;
        q.put(rows)
        print("launching async proc")
        with Pool(processes=2) as ppool:         
           result = ppool.apply_async(PrintRows,(rows,))    
        print("Done launching async process")
        rows = cursor.fetchmany()

TheMainQuery()

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print("All done!\n")
return
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Problem:  It is not writing the data to the file at all. Af if the function is not getting executed at all. My goal is to have the spooling task executed asynchronously. 
Any tips/samples will be highly appreciated.

thanks much !!!.

Comment: What is `Pool` exactly?

Comment: I suppose its a pool of processes? Like 2 processes in this case. To be honest, I got that piece of code from web.

Comment: From which module is your `Queue` class imported? `queue.Queue` or `multiprocessing.Queue`?

Comment: After passing 'rows' to the function instead of using the queue, i still don't see the function getting invoked because the message in the print function is not getting printed. Also the csv file is not getting created .

Comment: It is important for us to know what you are doing. There are many different types of pool. If you spawning multiple processes every process will have its own queue and if you put it in the main queue the worker processes will not receive it.

Comment: I am importing from multiprocessing.Queue as below:

Comment: *spool the chunk of data asynchronously(using CVS_Writer) to a file*: You can't wirte to **one** csv file parallel.

Comment: I am actually creating a new file for every process. Atleast for now, if each process can write to a file that will be ok.

Comment: I was able to make it work by moving the process pool definition out of the loop where apply_async function was called. Currently I am defining the pool before calling the apply_async function. Instead I defined the 'ppool = Pool(processes=12)' before the loop itself. Then it is working. All processes can append to one file when I open it in append mode ('a'). Thanks for your help.